# How can I solve the mutating table error here?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

```
set serveroutput on;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER hw3
BEFORE DELETE on ENROLLS
for EACH ROW
ENABLE
DECLARE
v_sid number;
v_term varchar2(20);
v_sectno number;
v_COMPNAME varchar2(20);
v_points number;
BEGIN
    select :old.SID,:old.TERM,:old.SECTNO into v_sid,v_term,v_sectno from enrolls;
    select COMPNAME,points into v_compname,v_points from scores
        where scores.sid=v_sid and scores.term=v_term and scores.sectno=v_sectno;
    INSERT into DELETED_SCORES (SID,TERM,SECTNO,compname,points)
        values (v_sid,v_term,v_sectno,v_compname,v_points);
    DELETE FROM SCORES
        WHERE SID=V_SID AND TERM=V_TERM AND SECTNO=V_SECTNO;
END;
/
```

There are two table, which is enrolls and scores. And SCORES table has a combined foreign keys including SID,TERM,AND SECTNO referring to table ENROLLS. 
The trigger is now successfully compiled, but there is a problem shown as below:

```
Error starting at line : 24 in command -
DELETE FROM enrolls
    WHERE SID=1111 and term='F12' and sectno=1031
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-04091: table C16_HE_JIEL.ENROLLS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "C16_HE_JIEL.HW3", line 8
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'C16_HE_JIEL.HW3'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.
```

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you don't like about the code sofar?

Comment: `from score,enrolls`? That looks wrong. You're creating a cartesian join between two tables and then not limiting it to create a sane join in the `WHERE` clause (I.e. nothing mentions `enrolls` there). Better (if the join is even needed) to use ANSI join syntax.

Comment: Any idea how I can do a change?

Comment: In order to suggest a change we need to know the column used to join score and enrolls, otherwise we cannot help you rewrite your join clause.
Attaching the structure of both tables to your post is a good practice when asking such questions.

Comment: I fix the join problem though here comes with a mutating problem.

Answer (score 0):

This select:

```
select :old.SID,:old.TERM,:old.SECTNO into v_sid,v_term,v_sectno from enrolls;
```

Is invalid for two reasons:

- you can't select from the table where the trigger fired on
- you are selecting ***all*** rows from that table, not just one.

The select isn't needed anyway, you can simply use the values in the `OLD` record directly (and remove the invalid `select ... from enrolls`)

```
select COMPNAME,points 
   into v_compname,v_points 
from scores
where scores.sid = :old.SID
  and scores.term = :old.TERM
  and scores.sectno = :old.SECTNO;
```

The above statement requires that the combination of `(sid, term, secno)` is unique in the table scores. If that is not the case and you need to insert *multiple* rows with into `deleted_scores` you need to use an `INSERT` based on a select.

Which then removes the need for variables completely. So the whole trigger can be simplified to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER hw3
  BEFORE DELETE on ENROLLS
  for EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT into DELETED_SCORES (SID,TERM,SECTNO,compname,points)
  select sid, term, sectno, compname, points 
  from scores
  where scores.sid = :old.SID
    and scores.term = :old.TERM
    and scores.sectno = :old.SECTNO;    

  DELETE FROM SCORES
  WHERE SID = :OLD.sid 
    AND TERM = :OLD.term
    AND SECTNO = :OLD.sectno;
END;
/
```

---

More details about the "table is mutating" restriction can be found in the manual:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS759

Comment: Thank you so much for you revise. Though, after the revise, another problem came out, which shown as : Error starting at line : 29 in command -
DELETE FROM enrolls
    WHERE SID=1111 and term='F12' and sectno=1031
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "C16_HE_JIEL.HW3", line 8
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'C16_HE_JIEL.HW3'
01422. 00000 -  "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"
*Cause:    The number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned.

Comment: @that means that the combination of (sid, term, sectno) is not unique in the scores table.

Answer (score 0):

never use before trigger for DML. In some situations before trigger can be fired more than once for the same row. It might happen in situations when your session is blocked by other session updating/deleting the same row.

Use compound trigger and apply DML changes in after trigger session.
Then you can be sure, that data you see are really correct.

The *mutating table error* means that Oracle can not quarantee that what you're doing is deterministic.